# Webapp to allow employees to claim one product in each of two categories

Tags: web-apps, shopping-cart

So our company disposes old IT equipment such as laptops and tablets to our employees for a very steep discount. This year we have a lot of assets to get rid off and was thinking of implementing a web app to make it easier for employees to claim products that they want. We would only allow an employee to claim one item of each category (laptop and tablet). This will also allow remote employees to partake in this activity.

Any ideas or solutions on how to implement this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You don't need online payments in this webapp, right?

Comment: Do you need to integrate with your company's authentication server (for instance LDAP)? Or will you somehow send a user/password or an invitation link to everyone? Or is it fine if the site has no authentication and people just fill their name? (probably OK for a small company with an intranet accessible via VPN)

Comment: Hi @NicolasRaoul! Thanks so much for the reply. 1) Yeah we won't need payments in this webapp. We'll be collecting payments in person in the office. 2) Nope, no integration required, we are a small company with about 200 people; so people filling in their name and email address works. :)

Comment: I guess our main priority is to make it easier for our employees especially remote employees to participate in the yardsale. In the past, we would just use a Google Sheet and open it up to the company and it was really messy and hectic. We are trying to make it fair and easier this year for our employees!

Comment: Hi. I guess it can be hosted on internet for remote access, or access to internal network. Any ecommerce cart system should work, with some rules to disable user adding more than one item in a category to shopping cart. If this sounds okay for you, I can make a couple of suggestions.